# Arithmetic operation from string

Tags: c#, math-expression-eval

I have a string like `str = " 4+ 6 * 30";`. I have to perform an arithmetic operation on this using C#; My solution to this problem is as follows.

```
     string temp = " 4 + 6 * 5";
     int firstNaum = 0;
     int secondNum = 0;
     int ThirdNum = 0;
     int finalResults = 0;
    //Spliting strings
    string[] withoutOperator = temp.Split('\t',' ','*' , '+');
    //Iterating strings 
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var res in withoutOperator)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(res) && counter ==1)
        {
            firstNaum = Convert.ToInt32(res);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(res) && counter== 4)
        {
            secondNum = Convert.ToInt32(res);
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(res) && counter == 7)
        {
            ThirdNum = Convert.ToInt32(res);
        }
        counter += 1;
    }
    finalResults = firstNaum + secondNum * ThirdNum;
```

Comment: The process that you're using is very tightly coupled to your example, and not at all extensible to other input strings.

Answer (score 16):

One of the simplest and easiest ways to evaluate math expressions is to use the Compute method of the DataTable class:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
int answer = (int)dt.Compute("2+(4*3)*4", "");
```

answer is 50.

One caveat you'll have to trap exceptions to catch invalid expressions.

Answer (score 10):

Your solution is **very** limited. As it only take a string in in the following format `x1 x2 x3`, and apply to the function `x1+x2*x3`.

To build an expressional calculator, you need to go through these steps :

1. Segmentate the expression into a list of tokens
2. Parse the tokens into recognizable lexemes(numbers, operator, parenthesis, etc)
3. Transform the list into a tree structure based on the order of operations
4. Calculate the result of top root, which requires the results from its branch(es)

Comment: However, such expressions are extremely easy to parse and calculate, as the [Shunting-Yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) can be used to evaluate the tokens. So of your four steps, only two remain: tokenization (I don't get why you split that into two phases), and evaluation via Shunting-Yard.

Answer (score 6):

Can you clarify what you want us to feed back on.

My thoughts are:

1. Use a library that already performs infix mathematical parsing because the process is relatively complex but has been "solved" many times before.
2. Your code assumes a very strict order in the the operations.  That doesn't make it very extensible.
3. Try adding validation.  instead of `Convert.ToInt32(res)`, use `int.TryParse(res, out n)`.  if the function returns false, you know the parse failed and you can handle it as you feel fit.
4. Maybe `Trim()` your res on each loop - although you will need to assign it to a new variable (e.g. `var res2 = res.Trim();`)

Answer (score 3):

I believe Jace.net is what you're looking for. [Here](https://github.com/pieterderycke/Jace) is the official Github link.

Here is a basic evaluation from a string expression:

```
CalculationEngine engine = new CalculationEngine();

Dictionary<string, double> variables = new Dictionary<string, double>();
variables.Add("var1", 2);

double result = engine.Calculate("5 % (2 + var1)", variables );
```

And here is an example calculating a math expression which has a log operator:

```
Dictionary<string, double> variables = new Dictionary<string, double>();
variables.Add("var1", 2.5);
variables.Add("var2", 3.4);

CalculationEngine engine = new CalculationEngine();
double result = engine.Calculate("logn(var1, var2)", variables);
```